# Can you tape a fan to a heatsink?

Tags: fan, heatsink

The old screws to the aftermarket fan I bought won't fit. Can I tape the new fan to the old heatsink?

This part of the heatsink doesn't come in contact with the processor. It sits on top of the motherboard which has some rubberized material covering it to separate the two surfaces.

What kind of tape should I use?

Comment: There isn't enough tape in the world to keep a fan moving at 9000+ RPMs stable.  You need to find new screws contact the manufacture of the aftermarket fan.  If you attempt to do this, I can guarantee, you will damage your hardware.

Comment: depending on the layout ZipTies can work. agrees there isnt a tape made in the world (other than some industrial stuff) that would last time and under temperatures, it would just make a mess and not work.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, yes you can... but I wouldn't recommend it.

Not only will doing this leave the fan unstable and prone to getting knocked off the heatsink (which could result in a lot of damage) - tape over the top of the fan to secure it will reduce airflow.

There's also the possibility that if the fan blades arent perfectly aligned, the fan will "walk" over time - becoming less and less useful until it falls off the heatsink.

Its far simpler, less dangerous and more effective to just buy some mroe screws

Comment: I doubt this'll work. Have you ever got tape near a big heat source? the glue will quickly unstick.

Answer (score 1):

Take both to the local hardware store (preferably a "mom and pop" store - you'll get MUCH better help). Screws can't cost .10c each. They'll get you screws that are long enough and small enough.

Comment: Please don't "sign" your posts—your username is already shown below the post.